# Reorder Category Filters

Tags: magento2, category, attributes, product-attribute, filter

Currently have an issue with a Magento 2 site that I am developing.

On the category view I have a left sidebar with my product filters which pull data from my product attributes.

The issue I am having is that Magento is placing a Category filter block above all of these and my client would like this to be moved to the bottom.

I cannot find documentation on the best way to do this, any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Go to

```
 Admin > Stores > Attributes > Product > Price > Attribute Information > Storefront Properties > Position > 5
```

Here "price" attribute is taken for example which is filterable in layered navigation

For example there are five filters and we want price in bottom , So its positioned at no 5

Comment: does it helped you ?

Comment: el precio es fácil porque es un atributo pero cómo lo haces con las categorías